# Total mechanical energy of two neutron stars orbiting a common center ($E=U+K$)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, newtonian-gravity, reference-frames, orbital-motion

> Suppose we have two neutron stars of mass $M$, orbiting a common centre at a distance $R$. (i.e. the two neutron stars are $2R$ apart from each other, and $R$ apart from the centre). I've attempted to calculate the total mechanical energy, though  I'm not sure which one is the correct answer.

Attempt:

$F=\frac{GMm}{r^2}=\frac{GM^2}{(2R)^2}=\frac{GM^2}{4R^2}$ (Newton's law of universal gravitation).

Consider one neutron star,

$F = Ma = \frac{Mv^2}{R}=\frac{GM^2}{4R^2}$ (centripetal force)

Therefore, $v=\sqrt{\frac{GM}{4R}}$ for one of the neutron stars

Hence, the Kinetic energy of one neutron star is

$K=\frac{GM^2}{8R}$,

making the total kinetic energy of the system:

$$K_{tot}=2K=\frac{GM^2}{4R}$$

Now, this is the part where I'm stuck.

We know that the potential energy of an orbit is given by $U=-\frac{GMm}{r}$, but in this case does $r=2R$ (i.e. the distance between the two neutron stars), or does $r=R$, the distance between a neutron star and its centre?

So depending on which expression for $U$ is correct, we would have either $$U=-\frac{GM^2}{R}$$ or $$U=-\frac{GM^2}{2R}$$

So our total mechanical energy $E=K_{tot}+U$ will be either $$E=-\frac{GM^2}{4R}$$ or $$E=-\frac{3GM^2}{4R}$$

By the way, if it helps, $U$ is defined as the **mutual potential energy between the two neutron stars.**

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The distance, R, treats the neutron stars as point particles - from their centers.  The distance to use for the potential energy is R, the distance from the center of the system (assuming they are in an approximately circular orbit).  To clear your head, use a different set of letters for your equations!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The centripetal acceleration is $Mv^2/R$ as the masses move in a circle of radius R.. The attraction is $GM^2/4R^2$. Equating the two gives $Mv^2 = GM^2/4R$, which is also the total kinetic energy. Add to that the potential energy of $-GM^2/2R$ and you arrive at $E=-GM^2/4R$.

Comment: Ahh, I knew it. Thanks very much! I did the wrong one in my exam :(  $E=−\frac{3GM^2}{4R}$.